# android eclipse IDE How to Create MultiDex Files -Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536 error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have updated my google play service from 13 to 21 and when i try to import google play service into my project **FOR GOOGLE MAP INTEGRATION** and when i try to run the app i am getting, the below error, But if i remove the google play service from my project it is running fine, please help me with this issue? and i am using eclipse .
and i have try allot but not able to find any solution with eclipse?

Please any one tell me how can i create multiDex files in Eclipse IDE for my project, the new google play service library are having 18k methods so is there any way to reduce the methods from google play services , I just want it for GOOGLE MAP INTEGRATION

```
 Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
    [2014-11-17 15:16:50 - TheGrooveboss] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

Comment: Vote to reopen the question. The 'duplicate' answer refers to Android Studio, not Eclipse, which doesn't have gradle files.